# iOS 11 & iOS 12 Locale.preferredLanguages returns only [en]

Tags: ios, locale, ios11, ios12

When running this app I get back an array of only en from preferredLanguages. In the settings I have 3 languages set.

If I delete and reinstall the app now preferredLanguages returns 3. Why is this? It used to see the changes once the springboard restarted and I launched the app?

Any help?

More Info --

Sure so I start the app and see english, this is fine. Then I go into my settings and change my languages by adding Spanish and Chinese I make Chinese first so my preferred is Chinese, Spanish, English in that order. When I save it and launch the app Locale.preferredLanguages only returns English. If I then delete the app and re install it now returns all three

Comment: Can you please provide more detail to help others reproduce what you're describing? Tried based on my understanding of what you've written and I am not seeing the same result.

Comment: Sure so I start the app and see english, this is fine. Then I go into my settings and change my languages by adding Spanish and Chinese I make Chinese first so my preferred is Chinese, Spanish, English in that order. When I save it and launch the app Locale.preferredLanguages only returns English. If I then delete the app and re install it now returns all three @shim

Comment: You can add the details as edits to your question.